# Variables in a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

So I've got the following problem:

> Find the values of $a$ for which the following system has:
>
> A. A unique solution
>
> B. An infinite number of solutions
>
> C. No solutions
>
> $$x+y-z=4$$
>   $$x+2y+z=7$$
>   $$3x+6y+(a^2 - 5a+9)z = a+18$$

I solved A by using Cramer's rule, expressing $x$, $y$ and $z$ in terms of $a$ and then replacing inside the first equation to find that $a=21$. However, I can't find a way to solve the other two. I thought about making the third equation a multiple of one of the other two but no value of $a$ satisfies that.

Sorry for formatting/english. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This system of equations "row-reduces" to

$$ \left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1&-1&4 \\0&1&2&3\\0&0&a^2-5a+6&a-3\\\end{array}\right) \ \ . $$

So we can answer the latter parts of the question first.  In order to have an infinite number of solutions (system is "dependent"), we would need to have $ \ (a-2) \ (a-3) \ = 0 \ \ $ *and* $ \ a-3 \ = \ 0 \ $ **simultaneously**, which occurs for $ \ a = 3 \ $.  In order to have *no* solutions (system is "inconsistent"), we require that $ \ (a-2) \ (a-3) \ = 0 \ $ , with $ \ a \ $ equal to anything *other than* 3 ; so $ \ a = 2 \ $ satisfies this condition.

Any other value of $ \ a \ $ leads to a unique solution of the system.

**EDIT --** Sorry, just corrected my factoring goof...

**Response to comments:**

I am getting for the numerators from Cramer's Rule

$$ x : \ \ a^2 \ - \ 2a \ - 3 \ = \ (a+1)(a-3) \ \ , $$

$$ y : \  \ 3a^2 \ - \ 17a \ + 24 \ = \ (a-\frac{8}{3})(a-3) \ \ , $$

$$ z : \  \ a-3 \ \ , $$

so all the numerators and the denominator are zero for $ \ a = 3 \ $ , which is the "dependent" case, and the denominator is also zero (with all numerators non-zero) for $ \ a = 2 \ , $ indicating "inconsistency".  [Thanks to WolframAlpha for assistance with the tedious determinant computations.  All the agony involved in that technique is why a lot of people generally use some "elimination" method, such as row-reduction or Gauss-Jordan...]

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean that not only 21 but any other $a$ (other than 2 and 3) leads to an unique solution? If so, why does Cramer's rule lead me to $a=21$? Did i do something wrong?

Comment: If you are looking at the determinant of the coefficient matrix, you should find it to be $ \ (a^2 - 5a + 6) \ $ , so there are just two values of $ \ a \ $ which cause that matrix to be singular.  All other values make the determinant non-singular, which means the system will have a unique solution.

Comment: Wow, I suck pretty badly at this. Thanks, that makes sense, I hadn't thought of that (clearly). I still don't understand why would Cramer's rule lead me to $a=21$, though. I guess I must've done something wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: When you say "Cramer's Rule", are you talking about the version for finding determinants of 3 x 3 matrices, or the version for solving a system using adjoints?  In either event, you want to be particularly careful about arithmetic when working in linear algebra.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the work you have been doing; it makes it a lot easier for someone on M.SE to "troubleshoot" difficulties.

Comment: Well, now I know I actually just did a lot of pointless calculations. Using Cramer's rule, I got that $$z=\frac {a+3}{a^2-5a+6}$$, $$x=\frac {a^2-4a-3}{a^2-5a+6}$$, and $$y=\frac {3a^2-17a+72}{a^2-5a+6}$$. I'm not sure what I did wrong, but replacing those in the first equation yields $a=21$.

Comment: What you are looking for here is that $ \ a = 2 \ $ or $ \ a = 3 \ $ make the denominators zero for all of these expressions, so those will not lead to a unique solution of the system [determinant of coefficient matrix is zero]. At present, I'd have to take your word on the adjoints (I think, though, at least one of the numerators may be incorrect).  What I'm finding on research is that the system is dependent if all three numerators also become zero, along with the denominator; the system is inconsistent if the denominator is zero and _not all_ of the numerators are.